# Format an object to split the header of the data

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a Typescript project where I want to change the format of a JSON object. The object I receive is an array of objects with the keys and the values, what I want is to separate the keys in the first array and then the data in each array.

The object I currently have is the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "ser": null,
    "IP": null,
    "host": "",
    "type": "Web",
    "auth": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "ser": null,
    "IP": "191.174.230.02",
    "host": "",
    "type": "Proxy",
    "auth": ""
  }
]
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[
    "id",
    "ser",
    "IP",
    "host",
    "type",
    "auth"
],
[
    "1",
    null,
    null,
    "",
    "Web",
    ""
],
[
    "2",
    null,
    "191.174.230.02",
    "",
    "Proxy",
    ""
]
```

This is the object that I want to get by adding the `values` property to it:`

```
{
  "values": [
    [
        "id",
        "ser",
        "IP",
        "host",
        "type",
        "auth"
    ],
    [
        "1",
        null,
        null,
        "",
        "Web",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "2",
        null,
        "191.174.230.02",
        "",
        "Proxy",
        ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use Object.keys(data[0]) to get the keys of the first element
2. iterate all elements with Object.values(element) to get each element data
3. push key and element value to array

Here is the code.

```
var data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    ser: null,
    IP: null,
    host: "",
    type: "Web",
    auth: "",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    ser: null,
    IP: "191.174.230.02",
    host: "",
    type: "Proxy",
    auth: "",
  },
];

var arr = [Object.keys(data[0])];
for (let element of data) {
  arr.push(Object.values(element));
}

var obj = { values: arr };
```

Comment: Ok that works, but is it possible to add a property to the final object? I have updated my question

Comment: use an object to store key "values" and arr, see my updated answer